# How to make a new dataframe from existig dataframe by averaging out some of the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has columns -

```
cols = group_dataframe.columns
print(cols)

Index(['TEST_TXT', 'count', 'mean', 'std', 'LSL', 'USL', 'median', 'Cp', 'CpK', 'Cpu', 'Cpl', 'min', 'max', '25%',
       '50%', '75%'],
      dtype='object')
```

I wish to make a new dataframe with mean of all the rows for certain columns like `"mean","std","Cp","Cpu"` but minimum and maximum for `"min"` and `"max"` column, also leave `test_txt` from processing.

My code looks like this -

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df["Group"] = np.asarray(test_group_name)

for col in cols:
    if col == "TEST_TXT":
        pass
    elif col in ["min","max"]:
        new_df[col] = np.min(group_dataframe[col].astype(float))
    else:
        new_df[col] = np.mean(group_dataframe[col].astype(float))
```

but this doesn't seem to fill dataframe at all. The new dataframe should have only one row, mean of values for a certain column and min/max for others. Can anyone help to find the error(if there is any), or suggest something better to achieve the same?

Comment: There is no need to loop over the columns, `pandas` provides functionality for that. You can have a look at `agg` or `apply`. If you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can provide better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first create a dictionary with the averages and then convert it into a DataFrame

```
res = {}
for col in cols:
    if col == "TEST_TXT":
        pass
    elif col in ["min","max"]:
        res[col] = np.min(group_dataframe[col].astype(float))
    else:
        res[col] = np.mean(group_dataframe[col].astype(float))

new_df = pd.DataFrame(res)
```

Comment: This seems for have solved the problem. But I don't understand which it worked this way and not the way I was doing it. Do you have any clue ?

Comment: Possibly. I do not know what `test_group_name` is in your statement `new_df["Group"] = np.asarray(test_group_name)` so that's worth checking. But the main thing that, I think, will fix your original code is to make rhs to be lists/arrays not floats, as in `new_df[col] = [np.min(group_da...]`

Comment: PS If `test_group_name` is a scalar then you also want something like this `new_df["Group"] = np.asarray([test_group_name])` or simply `new_df["Group"] = [test_group_name]

Comment: "test_group_name" is simply a variable, string variable to be more precise.

Answer (score 2):

`aggregate` seem to answer you needs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,4)), columns=['count', 'dummy', 'mean', 'max'])
df.agg({'count': 'mean', 'mean':'mean', 'max':'max'})
```

Here I create a `Dataframe` with 4 columns and aggregate columns of interest with specific function. The result is a `Series`

```
count    0.493802
mean     0.532349
max      0.676727
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I wanted a dataframe instead. But it also solved the problem. +1

Comment: You can create a dataframe from the solution by @igrinis as such `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,4)), columns=['count', 'dummy', 'mean', 'max'])
res = df.agg({'count': 'mean', 'mean':'mean', 'max':'max'})
df_res = pd.DataFrame(res).transpose()
`

Comment: @piterbarg Great. Thanks for quick info.